# Setting up a shadow catcher layer in Cinema4D Lite

Tags: cinema4d

What's the best way to set up a shadow catcher using Cineware Cinema 4D lite and After Effects?

I'm following the tutorial [Shadow Catcher plugin in Cinema 4D](https://grafxflow.co.uk/blog/3d-animation/shadow-catcher-plugin-in-cinema-4d), 
but it's not working in AE.

I've installed the plugin in

```
/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2019/Plug-ins/MAXON CINEWARE AE/(CINEWARE Support)/lite/plugins
```

(not sure whether this is doable).

Any tips?